# Can I add a CSS3 gradient to Google Visualizations Bubble Chart background?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I'm creating a bubble chart with the Google Visualizations API and have a nice looking chart that I'm happy with. Using the API reference documentation, I've made some custom changes to the appearance of the chart

```
var options = {
    title: 'Cool Chart',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'System Score',
        baseline: 0,
        maxValue: 4,
        ticks: [2,4]
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Financial Score',
        baseline: 0,
        maxValue: 4,
        ticks: [2,4]
    },

    bubble: {
        textStyle: {fontSize: 11},
        opacity: .6
            },

    series: {'High': {color: 'red'},
            'Medium': {color: 'yellow'},
             'Low': {color: 'green'}                           
            },

    sizeAxis: {
        minValue: 3.5,
        maxValue: 25,
            },

    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: '#123456'
        }
```

The chartArea.backgroundColor is where I'm looking for guidance. I've added a hex color here, no problem. But I'd love is to replace that with a CSS3 gradient like this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff120a 0%, #f8fc02 47%, #4bd31d 100%);
```

(I know that's just for Mozilla...)

I've scoured the API documentation to see if there's a way to do this - but I'm hoping they just left out this part.

Does anyone know if this is do-able...and if so, how to do it?

I can knock it out in straight CSS - but when put in JavaScript, I lose traction.

Thanks for reading and I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: Did you find a solution?